# MyBatis/Spring - 2 Datasources MyBatisSystemException - Ambigous mapped statements

Tags: spring, ibatis, mybatis

I  have configured two datasources in my Spring/MyBatis application. I don't get any error while startup (its reading the Mapper XML and interface). But when invoking the method, its throwing the following exception:

MyBatisSystemException: SqlSession operation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: selectByPrimaryKey is ambiguous in Mapped Statements collection (try using the full name including the namespace, or rename one of the entries)

It doesn't quite clearly say the cause for ambiguity.

Comment: Please, post here your Spring and MyBatis config files.

Comment: MyBatis is saying in your mapper xml files you have configured more than one statement with id="selectByPrimaryKey". To invoke a specific statement invoke the statement with namespace prefix.